# laravel 4.1 Controller method .... not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have this code but my Method not find ?

Route.php

```
Route::controller('Basic', 'BasicController');
```

BasicController.php

```
class BasicController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

    public function getTest()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

when i call test from browser : `http://mydomain.dev/Basic/Test Not Work ! 
and get this error :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException 
>   Controller method [Test] not found.

```
open: /var/www/mydomain.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function missingMethod($method, $parameters = array())
{
    throw new NotFoundHttpException("Controller method [{$method}] not found.");
}
```

Why ?

My laravel version is 4.1.8

Comment: My index Method is Work !!!

Comment: Have you tried `http://mydomain.dev/Basic/test`?

Comment: Are you actually sending get requests to that controller?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Yes I try,

Comment: @Zarazthuztra when i used [code]mydomain.dev/Basic/Test[code] then Send a Get Request to controller

Comment: @user1873569 Just checking. I always ask the "is it plugged in" questions.

Comment: @user1873569 Not a problem. Stuff like that happens to me more than I'd like to admit. You spend an hour trying to find the problem and when you do find it you're like...duh..I'm an idiot..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute

```
artisan routes
```

You probably will see those routes

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                    | Name       | Action                         | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET Basic/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |            | BasicController@getIndex       |                |               |
|        | GET Basic                                              |            | BasicController@getIndex       |                |               |
|        | GET Basic/test/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |            | BasicController@getTest        |                |               |
|        | GET Basic/{_missing}                                   |            | BasicController@missingMethod  |                |               |
|        | GET test                                               |            | Closure                        |                |               |
```

If you say that your index is working:

So you need hit the route

```
http://mydomain.dev/Basic/test
```

and **not**

```
http://mydomain.dev/Basic/Test
```